# Python networking using anaconda

Tags: python

Create sockets for server and client machines using Anaconda, showing successful
communication between the two. Ensure that you include detailed documentation explaining the
sockets that have been created

Comment: Hey this site is not for posting homework assignments.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! To get help from this community, please share the code you've already tried, what other resources you've looked at, and the specific place you're stuck.

Answer (score -1):

You should start from reading the python docs, starting from socket and tcp/ip programming . There you will have examples of what you have to do in this exercise.

Anaconda is python package collection /manager and software with some additional tools/IDE the socket implementation has nothing to do with it .